# Outcome of this simple java program?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class NotActuallyImmutable {
  private final int x;

  public NotActuallyImmutable(int x) {
    this.x = x;// line 1
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }
}


public class Mutable extends NotActuallyImmutable {
  private int x = 123;

  public Mutable(int x) {
    super(x);
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x++;
  }
}
```

now in my main class

```
    NotActuallyImmutable n = new Mutable(42); // line2
    int x = n.getX();
    System.out.println("x is"+x);
```

I am expecting the output as 42 but it return the output as 123. I am expecting 42 because at line 2 I am making object of class Mutable and then at line 1 I am setting value as 42. so when i do `n.getX()` I should get the this latest value not the default 123. I know Ii am missing something but not able to figure out the logic behind it?

Comment: Are you sure you can compile above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the field `x` in `Mutable` and the field `x` in class `NotActuallyImmutable` are not the same. The `x` that is returned by `getX()` is the one in `Mutable` (because the `getX()` that is invoked is `Mutable.getX()`, not `NotActuallyImmutable.getX()`).

Note that if you removed the instance field from `Mutable`, then you would have a compiler error because `NotActuallyImmutable.x` is private to `NotActuallyImmutable` and not accessible to any code in `Mutable`.

If you made `NotActuallyImmutable.x` a protected field, then `Mutable.x` would shadow it and you would still have the same behavior. If you removed `Mutable.x` in this case, you would still have a compiler error because you were trying to increment a `final` field.

If you remove `Mutable.getX()`, then the `x` that would be returned by `getX()` would be `NotActuallyImmutable.x`, despite there being another field of the same name in `Mutable`.

Comment: I wouldn't used the term "shadows" in this situation.  To me "shadows" suggests that the first variable would be accessible if the second wasn't there, but in this case you wouldn't be able to access the first `x` even if the second didn't exist.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard - Yeah, I saw your comment pop up just as I was fixing my language.

Answer (score 2):

The `private int x` in `Mutable` and the `private int x` in `NotActuallyImmutable` are completely different fields that just have the same name.

This isn't a problem for the compiler because you can't access a `private` field from another class.  So as far as the compiler is concerned, when you define `Mutable`, the `x` in `NotActuallyImmutable` is invisible and might as well not exist.

It is of course confusing for the programmer.  If you rename one of the fields to `y` (and the getter method to `getY`) the behaviour seems much more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
NotActuallyImmutable n = new Mutable(42); // line2
```

This means you have an object of type NotActuallyImmutable but the instance of created object is Mutable.
so in this code your dealing with Mutable object which will return 123. as the number you passed is saved in NotActuallyImmutable not in Mutable,

Answer (score 0):

`n` has two different `x` values which are visible in different contexts, the parent class's private member variable and the child class's private member variable.

```
NotActuallyImmutable n = new Mutable(42); // line2
```

Creates a new `Mutable`.  Executes `parent(x)` which sets the parent class's `x` to 42.

```
int x = n.getX();
```

`n` is a `Mutable` instance so this calls `Mutable`'s `getX()` which returns `Mutable`'s value for `x` (123) rather than the parent's.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nice explanations given in above answers. But to to just brief the final understanding. As i am doing  new Mutable(42).getX(), jvm first will look in Mutable object to get the value of X not inside NotActuallyImmutable.  If i remove getX() method from Mutable , i get the expected(as per my expectation) value i.e 42.

This example gets messy becoz variable name i.e X is same in parent and child class but good for understanding concept